# GitHub repository location for Import scripts via Kettle

Tags: import

In post:
http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=35438.0

JonGold states that he'll share the import scripts for using Kettle to import via cli.php and then tag the new imports, again using cli.php.  Unfortunately I haven't found a link.  Anyone have that link?  (I've sent a PM to JonGold, but also said I'd create the question so that he could reply to the now locked post.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check the repo located here,  you might need to search the repo further:
 https://github.com/PalanteJon/civicrm_kettle_transforms

Comment: This is the correct answer! I have other scripts that import tags, but this one is representative.

Comment: Thanks Jon, and thanks again for all your work on using Kettle with Civi